# QR decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, algorithms, matrix

I have a matrix which is "almost" like an upper triangular just that the last row has non zero elements. And I want to perform the QR decomposition on that matrix.

Does anyone know the "name" of such a matrix? And also since I don't want to use the built in matlab QR function for such a matrix, can anyone suggest a better algorithm for me to use?

Comment: Have you considered the Cholesky decomposition, please? Or LU decomposition? I use R rather than Matlab, but I believe that those may be effective for your problem. Would you happen to have a small numeric example, by any chance?

Comment: The main idea is to observe the sensitivity of the diagonal elements. The original matrix was a full matrix where I used the built in matlab function QR to decompose it. But now I have purturbed (R+E) the R upper triangular matrix of the decomposition with E( E is an NxN matrix with its elements all zeros except at the last row where it has non zero elements) The shape of (R+E) is almost like the Upper triangular matrix R since it has zeros below its diagonal except it's last row.

Comment: I am expected to take the QR decomposition of this new matrix (R+E) in other to observe how sensitive the diagonal elements of R with respect to (E) is. I no longer want to use the matlab QR built function since this new matrix is (almost upper triangular except at the last row where you have non zero elements). I do have numeric examples but since I'm new here, I don't know how to type in matrices.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @user1544953 Cholesky only works for SPD matrices. I doubt that the matrix here is symmetric.

Answer (score 4):

Look at section 5 of http://web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/papers/ggms74.pdf to see how to update QR decomposition when a row is added to the matrix you wish to factorize.  You may find it not so easy to fully digest.

I think algorithm 6.16 of [Chapter 6 of Scientific Computing - An Introduction using Maple and MATLAB](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCsQFjACahUKEwjvnff54JnIAhUCFR4KHfAlDgY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9783319043241-c1.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-1453619-p176445658&usg=AFQjCNHwL1jRh_kEY-7ySZXHAQAQjrn27A&sig2=cBASIpwNUnM5L4pmvXpJ3g&cad=rja) will do the trick for you, allowing you to update in MATLAB an existing QR factorization when you add a row to the matrix you wish to factorize.  Here are the MATLAB m files http://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/GVL4/M-Files/Chapter%206/Chap6.htm .

Answer (score 2):

If the matrix is almost triangular, you can just update the QR to get rid of the unwanted non-zeros. You can do that by using Givens rotations (see Golub and Van-Loan, "Matrix Computations" 4th edition, Chapter 6.5).

You can also use MATLAB's "qrinsert" and add the additional row to the QR factorization.